# how to get and pass value from JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield

I've created class with JTextField and I want to get this value and use in other class.

```
public class Create{
 JTextField user;

public Create(){
  user =new JTextField(10);
  }
public  String getUser(){
  return user.getText();
  }



public class ReviewWindow{
 JLabel luser1;
 public ReviewWindow(){
  Create create = new Create();
  luser1= new JLabel(create.getUser()); //I want to get this value here.
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Your textfield is empty because you never placed any text there to begin with

Comment: yes.it should .you must create frame and add textfield to it.then enter some text and get the value

Comment: if i use user.get(text); in public class Create then everything it's ok

Comment: i know it. I just paste the most important part of code

Comment: this seems ok.could you post entire code somewhere and link it here

Answer (score 0):

So usually there is an action that is associated with getting a value from a JTextField. For example a button named "save" that is pressed once the user is finished typing in the JTextfield. So set up a button (an tutorial/explanation can be found [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jbutton/set-action-command-for-jbutton/)) add an action listener to that button. Inside that actionlistener function, grab the text from JtextField (JtextField.getText()) and pass it to your other class via a getter/setter function or constructor.